# Converter LocalDate para LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, datetime, data

Possuo em minha classe de Filtro os seguintes atributos:

```
private LocalDate periodoDe;
private LocalDate periodoAte;
```

Porém, o objeto no qual estão as informações o atributo que será filtrado é um `LocalDateTime`, logo, em meus testes, não posso fazer isso:

```
filtro.setPeriodoDe(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 17));
filtro.setPeriodoAte(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 21));
```

Ou seja, preciso estar preparado para receber um `LocalDate` mas tenho que converter para um `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) só possui a data (dia, mês e ano) e [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) possui a data e hora. Para fazer a conversão, você precisa definir o horário que será usado. Alguns exemplos:

```
LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 17);
// seta o horário para 10:30
LocalDateTime dt = data.atTime(10, 30);

// seta o horário para 10:30:45
LocalDateTime dt = data.atTime(10, 30, 45);

// seta o horário para 10:30:45.123
LocalDateTime dt = data.atTime(10, 30, 45, 123000000);
```

A API tem precisão de nanossegundos, o que quer dizer que é possível ter até 9 casas decimais na fração de segundos:

```
// seta o horário para 10:30:45.123456789
LocalDateTime dt = data.atTime(10, 30, 45, 123456789);
```

---

No caso de um filtro de busca, é comum que a data inicial tenha o horário setado para meia-noite e a data final para 23:59:59.999 (para ter certeza que vai considerar todo o dia na busca).

Sendo assim, você poderia fazer:

```
filtro.setPeriodoDe(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 17).atStartOfDay());
filtro.setPeriodoAte(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 21).atTime(LocalTime.MAX));
```

[`atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) seta o horário para meia-noite. E [`LocalTime.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) é uma constante que vale `23:59:59.999999999`.

---

### Timezones e horário de verão

Só lembrando que `LocalDateTime` não possui timezone, portanto não leva em consideração os efeitos de horário de verão, por exemplo.

Neste caso, você precisaria de um [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), e para isso precisaria definir um timezone também:

```
// seta o horário para 10:30 no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ZonedDateTime zdt = data.atTime(10, 30).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));

// seta o horário para início do dia no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ZonedDateTime zdt = data.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

Um exemplo é quando começa o horário de verão no Brasil: à meia-noite o relógio é adiantado para 01:00. Isso quer dizer que neste dia, todos os horários entre 00:00 e 00:59 não existem neste timezone. [`atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) já verifica isso e seta o horário para 01:00, que é o primeiro horário válido neste caso.

---

Já para obter o final do dia, é um pouco mais complicado. Quando termina o horário de verão no Brasil, por exemplo: à meia-noite o relógio é atrasado em uma hora, de volta para 23:00. Isso significa que todos os horários entre 23:00 e 23:59 existem 2 vezes neste dia (uma no horário de verão e outra no horário "normal").

Por isso setar o horário para `LocalTime.MAX` em um `ZonedDateTime` nem sempre vai funcionar. O jeito mais garantido é obter o início do dia seguinte e subtrair 1 nanossegundo. Assim, tem-se o último instante do dia, no timezone, independente das mudanças de horário de verão que porventura possam ter.

```
// seta o horário para o final do dia no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ZonedDateTime zdt = data
    // início do dia seguinte no timezone
    .plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))
    // menos 1 nanossegundo
    .minusNanos(1);
```

O nome do timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`) faz parte da lista de timezones [definidos pela IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Você pode obter a lista de todos os disponíveis usando [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--). Também é possível usar o timezone *default* da JVM usando [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--).

Claro que aí você teria que mudar sua busca para usar `ZonedDateTime`, mas aí fica a seu critério se vai considerar os efeitos do horário de verão ou não.

Comment: Só tenho dúvidas se isso funciona quando o horário de verão inicia ou termina ou quando ocorre mudança de fuso horário (não sei, vou fazer uns testes). Mas de qualquer forma a sua resposta está muito boa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa `LocalDateTime` não levam em conta o horário de verão nem quaisquer regras de timezones. Atualizei a resposta, valeu!

Comment: Ficou excelente!