# NullPointerException ao tentar logar no sistema dentro no netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Logo depois que fiz algumas substituições de ícones na tela principal e na tela de sobre, passou a ocorrer o erro `NullPointerException`, não faço ideia de como prosseguir e continuar o curso que estou fazendo. Uso MySQL, e lá está tudo certinho, foi depois de mudar os ícones mesmo. Segue o código abaixo,
Print do Erro: [image: erro]

```
package br.com.infox.telas;

import java.sql.*;
import br.com.infox.dal.ModuloConexao;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TelaLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conexao = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public void logar() {
        String sql = "select * from tbusuarios where login=? and senha=?";
        try {
            //as linhas abaixo preparam a consulta ao banco em função do
            //que foi digitado nas caixas de texto. O ? é substituido pel
            //conteúdo das variáveis
            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText());

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {               
                String perfil = rs.getString(6);               

                if (perfil.equals("admin")) {
                    TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                    principal.setVisible(true);
                    TelaPrincipal.menRel.setEnabled(true);
                    TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                    TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                    this.dispose();
                } else {
                    TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                    principal.setVisible(true);                    
                    TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    this.dispose();
                }


                conexao.close();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    public TelaLogin() {
        initComponents();
        conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();       

        if (conexao != null) {
            lblStatus.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/dbok.png")));
        } else {
            lblStatus.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/dberro.png")));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtSenha = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("X System - Login");
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setText("          Usuário");

        jLabel2.setText("  Senha");

        btnLogin.setText("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblStatus.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/dbok.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 328, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtUsuario)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnLogin))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                        .addComponent(lblStatus)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnLogin))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(lblStatus)))
                .addGap(42, 42, 42))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(599, 262));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //chamando o método logar
        logar();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaLogin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLogin;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtSenha;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUsuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
package br.com.infox.telas;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TelaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TelaPrincipal() {
        initComponents();    }


    private void initComponents() {

        desktop = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        lblUsuario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblData = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Menu = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        menCad = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        menCadCli = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        menCadOs = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        menCadUsu = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        menRel = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        menRelServ = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        MenAju = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        menAjuSob = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        menOpc = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        menOpcSair = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("X - Sistema de Controle de Ordem de Serviço");
        setResizable(false);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowActivated(evt);
            }
        });

        desktop.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(630, 470));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout desktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(desktop);
        desktop.setLayout(desktopLayout);
        desktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 630, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        desktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 470, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        lblUsuario.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        lblUsuario.setText("Usuário");

        lblData.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        lblData.setText("Data");

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/systemLogo (2).png"))); // NOI18N

        lblLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/systemLogo.png"))); // NOI18N

        menCad.setText("Cadastro");

        menCadCli.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_C, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        menCadCli.setText("Cliente");
        menCad.add(menCadCli);

        menCadOs.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_O, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        menCadOs.setText("Ordem de Serviço");
        menCad.add(menCadOs);

        menCadUsu.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_U, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        menCadUsu.setText("Usuário");
        menCadUsu.setEnabled(false);
        menCadUsu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                menCadUsuActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menCad.add(menCadUsu);

        Menu.add(menCad);

        menRel.setText("Relatório");
        menRel.setEnabled(false);

        menRelServ.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menRelServ.setText("Serviços");
        menRel.add(menRelServ);

        Menu.add(menRel);

        MenAju.setText("Ajuda");

        menAjuSob.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F1, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menAjuSob.setText("Sobre");
        menAjuSob.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                menAjuSobActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        MenAju.add(menAjuSob);

        Menu.add(MenAju);

        menOpc.setText("Opções");

        menOpcSair.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menOpcSair.setText("Sair");
        menOpcSair.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                menOpcSairActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menOpc.add(menOpcSair);

        Menu.add(menOpc);

        setJMenuBar(Menu);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(desktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(lblData)))
                    .addComponent(lblLogo))
                .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(lblData)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(lblLogo)
                .addGap(87, 87, 87))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(desktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(869, 523));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void menCadUsuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // as linhas abaixo abrir o form TelaUsuario dentro do desktop pane
        TelaUsuario usuario = new TelaUsuario();
        usuario.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(usuario);
    }                                         

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        // as linhas abaixo subsituem a label Data lblData, pela data atual do sistema ao inicializar o form.
        Date data = new Date();
        DateFormat formatador = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        lblData.setText(formatador.format(data));
    }                                    

    private void menOpcSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // exibe uma caixa de diálogo antes de sair do sistema
        int sair = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Tem certeza que deseja sair?","Atenção",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (sair == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }                                          

    private void menAjuSobActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //chamando a tela sobre
        TelaSobre sobre = new TelaSobre();
        sobre.setVisible(true);

    }                                         


    public static void main(String args[]) {     

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaPrincipal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenu MenAju;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar Menu;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane desktop;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblData;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblLogo;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel lblUsuario;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem menAjuSob;
    private javax.swing.JMenu menCad;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem menCadCli;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem menCadOs;
    public static javax.swing.JMenuItem menCadUsu;
    private javax.swing.JMenu menOpc;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem menOpcSair;
    public static javax.swing.JMenu menRel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem menRelServ;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
package br.com.infox.telas;

public class TelaSobre extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public TelaSobre() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowActivated(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Sistema para Controle de Ordem de Serviços");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Desenvolvido por: Carlos Eduardo ");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Sob a licença GPL");

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/infox/icones/about.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(152, 152, 152)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(392, 294));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaSobre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaSobre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaSobre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaSobre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaSobre().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
package br.com.infox.dal;

import java.sql.*;


public class ModuloConexao {
    //método responsável por estabelecer a conexão com o banco
    public static Connection conector() {
        java.sql.Connection conexao = null;
     // a linha abaixo chama  o driver que importei para a biblioteca
     String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     // armazenando informações referente ao banco
     String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbinfox";
     String user="root";
     String password ="";
     //estabelecendo a conexão com o banco

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            return conexao;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //a linha abaixo serve de apoio para esclarecer o erro
            //System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Eduardo, seja muito bem vindo ao stackoverflow. Pela experiencia que tenho com Java e TI no modo geral, da forma que estas descrevendo o problema, seria muito difícil encontrá-lo, você já aprendeu a usar o modo *debug* de sua IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Olhe isso:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //a linha abaixo serve de apoio para esclarecer o erro
        //System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
```

Esse `return null;` é uma ideia muito, mas muito, mas MUITO ruim! Além de fazer com que qualquer código que tente conectar no banco de dados, se encontrar um erro, tenha como resultado um `NullPointerException`, ele ainda por cima esconde e engole a causa real do erro. A solução é simplesmente deixar o `SQLException` ser lançado, afinal de contas, ele foi inventado para isso e está lá por uma boa razão. Tentar enterrar ou esconder o erro não é boa ideia.

Vamos reescrever o código dessa sua última classe, considerando [essa resposta antiga minha para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172816/132):

```
package br.com.infox.dal;

import java.sql.*;

public class ModuloConexao {

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbinfox";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

    //método responsável por estabelecer a conexão com o banco
    public static Connection conector() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Vamos ver o seu método `logar`:

```
Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public void logar() {
    String sql = "select * from tbusuarios where login=? and senha=?";
    try {
        //as linhas abaixo preparam a consulta ao banco em função do
        //que foi digitado nas caixas de texto. O ? é substituido pel
        //conteúdo das variáveis
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {               
            String perfil = rs.getString(6);               

            if (perfil.equals("admin")) {
                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);
                TelaPrincipal.menRel.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);                    
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                this.dispose();
            }


            conexao.close();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Bem, aqui há vários problemas:

- Use o *try-with-resources* adequadamente. Veja mais [nesta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).
- Não coloque o `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` e `ResultSet` como variáveis de instância. Eles são recursos caros e efêmeros que devem ser fechados e descartados depois de usados. Ao colocá-los como variáveis de instância, fica bem difícil controlar o tempo de vida deles adequadamente.
- Há código repetido dentro do `if` e do `else`. Quando isso acontece, quase sempre você pode mover o código para fora do `if`.
- Você viu que você inicializa a variável `conexao` com `null` e no método `logar()` você faz um `conexao.prepareStatement(sql)`? Pois é, isso vai te dar um belo `NullPointerException`.
- Ah, mas há aquele `conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();` e com isso o `conexao` não daria `NullPointerException`. Ocorre que se o `conector()` engolir e esconder o erro, ele vai sim. Pois bem, remova essa linha, pois a conexão é efêmera (tal como já explicado) e deve ser tratada com o *try-with-resources*. A menos que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo (não é o que o código demonstra), o melhor é conectar, usar a conexão, e tão logo seja possível, fechá-la e descartá-la.

Para reescrever esse método, vamos começar pela `TelaPrincipal`. Vamos começar com esse código:

```
            if (perfil.equals("admin")) {
                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);
                TelaPrincipal.menRel.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);                    
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                this.dispose();
            }
```

Isso pode ser simplificado para isso:

```
            TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
            principal.setVisible(true);
            TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
            if (perfil.equals("admin")) {
                TelaPrincipal.menRel.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            this.dispose();
```

Mas isso ainda não está muito bom. Observe essas instruções:

```
TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
TelaPrincipal.menRel.setEnabled(true);
TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
```

Elas evidenciam que você está fazendo mal-uso do `static` dentro da classe `TelaPrincipal`:

```
public static javax.swing.JLabel lblUsuario;
public static javax.swing.JMenuItem menCadUsu;
public static javax.swing.JMenu menRel;
```

Todas elas deveriam ser `private` e sem `static`. Atributos públicos são quase sempre uma péssima ideia, pior ainda quando estáticos. As exceções a isso são apenas alguns casos de constantes e objetos imutáveis ou singletons. Desse jeito que está, isso é uma violação do encapsulamento. Falo mais disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132) (junto com mais um monte de outras coisas).

Para arrumar isso, após voltar todos eles para `private` e sem `static`, crie esse construtor de `TelaPrincipal`, incorporando parte do código que estava em `logar()`:

```
public TelaPrincipal(boolean admin, String nome) {
    initComponents();
    if (admin) {
        this.menRel.setEnabled(true);
        this.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
        this.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
    }
    this.lblUsuario.setText(nome);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Delete então o construtor antigo:

```
public TelaPrincipal() {
    initComponents();    }
```

Na classe `TelaPrincipal`, delete também o método `main`. O único `main` que importa é o da `TelaLogin`.

Agora, vamos reescrever o método `logar()`:

```
public void logar() {
    String sql = "select * from tbusuarios where login=? and senha=?";
    String perfil = "", nome = "";

    try (
            Connection conexao = ModuloConexao.conectar();
            PreparedStatement pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText());

        try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            if (!rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)");
                return;
            }
            perfil = rs.getString(6);
            nome = rs.getString(2);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return;
    }

    new TelaPrincipal(perfil.equals("admin"), nome);
    this.dispose();
}
```

Outras dicas:

- Não use `System.exit(0);`. Isso é uma má prática de programação. É o botão de autodestruição da sua aplicação. Ao usar isso, não dá para salvar, não dá para fechar arquivos abertos, nem nada. Ao invés disso, chame o método `dispose()` do seu `JFrame`. Já falei disso também numa [resposta antiga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278823/recursividade-em-java-mdc/278831#comment569728_278831).
- As classes `Date` e `DateFormat` já morreram, mas esqueceram de enterrar. Tente não usá-las nunca mais. Ao invés disso, use `LocalDate` ou `LocalDateTime` no lugar de `Date` e `DateTimeFormatter` no lugar de `DateFormat`. Veja mais disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132) e/ou [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/330761/132).
- Não misture nas mesmas classes, a lógica de apresentação (que usa o swing) com lógica de banco de dados (que usa o JDBC). O motivo é que você não deveria querer que a sua lógica de acesso a dados fique amarrada ao swing e nem que as regras de visualização do sistema fiquem amarradas a detalhes do banco de dados. Essa separação é feita por meio da aplicação do padrão MVC.

Comment: agradeço muito pelo importantíssimo comentário Victor Stafusa! para iniciantes como eu, isso é um estímulo incrível!